# Calculate average in Dictionary <string, List<double>> C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I need calculate the average of a List into a dictionary, I´m start using this syntax to access to the double List and gets the average but the compiler give an error, I´m new working with dictionarys, how is the correct syntax to access each double List and gets the average?

Here is the example of my code:

```
Dictionary<string, List<double>> SignalValues =
    new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();

var dSignalAvg = SignalValues
                 .Where(x => x.Key == "Key")
                 .Average(x => x.Value);
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, do you want to calculate the average of a single list with a specific key or the total average of all the lists in the dictionary?

Comment: Hi Dimitris, I need calculate the average fo a single list with a specific key, sorry if I don´t asked with the correct undertand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

Given a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string,List<double>> values = new Dictionary<string,List<double>>();
```

Getting the average for a specific key is easy:

```
double avgValue = values
                  .Where( x => x.Key == "Key")
                  .Select( x => x.Value.Average() )
                  .FirstOrDefault()
                  ;
```

Or, if you want to reduce your dictionary to a dictionary of averages, it's just:

```
Dictionary<string,double> avgValues = values
                                      .ToDictionary(
                                        x => x.Key ,
                                        x => x.Value.Average()
                                      )
                                      ;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that the specific key exists in the dictionary then you can simply do:

```cs
var dSignalAvg = SignalValues["Key"].Average();
```

The code above will throw an exception if the dictionary doesn't have a key that equals "Key". If you want to check first, you can use `TryGetValue` like this:

```cs
double dSignalAvg = 0;

if (SignalValues.TryGetValue("Key", out List<double> signalList))
{
    dSignalAvg = signalList.Average();
}
```

Comment: That code looks very different from what OP shown in the question (filter by "Key")... You probably should clarify what you are answering.